# Pass initialized object to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, object

I have the following initialized object, and I want to pass this object through onclick function, is this possible to achieve?

```
var nameObject = { Name: "Stack", lastName:"Exchange" }
```

Here is my code:

In the `document ready` I have *link* with `onclick` function that is append into *html* element.

***Html:***

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

***Javascript:***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var nameObject = { Name: "Stack", lastName:"Exchange" };

  $("#test").append('<a href="#"'
  +'onclick="sendObj(**I want to pass "nameObject" into this function)">'
  +'sendObject</a>');
)};

function sendObj(**receive the object**)
{
  //nameObject.Name+" "nameObject.lastName;
}
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6ghj/)**

Comment: What do you mean by "sending"?? nameObject and sendObj are within the same scope so the sendObj function has access to the nameObject variable.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is not working in your fiddle?

Comment: this is not working -> http://jsfiddle.net/C6ghj/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var nameObject = { Name: "Stack", lastName:"Exchange" };

  $("#test").append('<a href="#" data-caller>sendObject</a>');

  $("#test").on("click", "[data-caller]", function() {
     sendObj(nameObject);
  });
)};

function sendObj(nameObject)
{
  alert(nameObject.Name+" "+nameObject.lastName);
}
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6ghj/14/)

Answer (score 4):

A more appropriate way of doing what you want is to store the object in the element's `data` object, which is what jQuery designates for this very purpose.

Then, assign a `click` handler that would call your desired function with the stored data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name = { Name: "Stack", lastName:"Exchange" };
    var a =  $('<a href="#">sendObject</a>').data('name', name).on('click',
       function(e){
           sendObj($(this).data('name'));
       });

    $("#test").append(a);
 });

function sendObj(e)
{
    console.log(e);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/C6ghj/25/) (say hello to console, ditch `alert()`).